# Samsung Intel Graphis HD 3000 + Nvidia GeForce GT 520MX

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install HD3000 drivers on ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151157/how-do-i-install-hd3000-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-04)

I just buy a Samsung NP300E5A-S05IT with a  Intel Graphis HD 3000 + Nvidia GeForce GT 520MX for 3D effect...

The propblem is that my ubuntu 12.04 not support Intel Graphics and also Nvidia 3D support

Some people have same problem? Exist a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance and sorry from my poor english

Walter

Comment: PLease see this answer - http://askubuntu.com/a/151164/35775

Answer (score -1):

You will have to manually download Nvidia drivers for your Graphics Card.

You can get it from here:
http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/45532

Intel HD Graphics is supported by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thats dual GPU config in notebook (nvida optimus). Downloading nvidia driver will cause a non gui system

Comment: What are you talking about? He says his Nvidia driver isnt functioning so he needs to download the Driver right?

Comment: no, he mentioned he has a dual graphics card  (read the question again). Search with the notebook model. It will say it has optimus. Now optimus is not supported by nvidia in linux and installing nvidia driver will give black screen.

Comment: Thanks guy for reply, so I've to wait from Hvidia?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics + Nvidia is not called dual graphics. Its just standard Dedicated + Integrated. Dual Graphics is like Nvidia + Nvidia/ATI + ATI etc.

Comment: @upapilot - please edit your answer with a clarification between dual GPU and dual integrated graphics etc.